# Set language for emails

Tags: php, laravel, email

I have alert system which sends emails to users. How can I send email in language based on user preference.

In users table I have a column `language`. It stores the users selected language ('en', 'de', etc...)

I send emails using this:

```
public function handle(){
...
Mail::send('emails.newSearchAlert', ['u' => $u, 'results' => $results], 
    function ($m) use ($u) {

        $m->from('noreply@mydomain.tv', 'My company');
}

        $m->to($u->email)->subject('Your search alert - ' . $u->search);
    });
```

In my `newSearchAlert` I do this:

```
@if(App::isLocale('de'))
    <h3>Ihr Alert</h3>
@elseif(App::isLocale('en'))
    <h3>Your campaign alert: </h3>
```

but it doesn't work. I always get emails in German language. How can I use `language` column from the table.

PS
I use this package for localization:
https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization

Comment: Do you set the locale based on your database entry before sending the email? Check App::setLocale($language)

Comment: Please display some more view code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set your locale before sending the E-Mail with

```
App::setLocale($language);
```

where `$language` is the language you load from your database

i think in your case it would be

```
App::setLocale($u->language);
```